# how to control concurrent operation of multiple users

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency

I'll try to put my question clear and concise, I'm developing a php based application for a courier company, in which multiple users can log into a page that consists of number of textbox fields and two buttons, the first button (Add New) is for auto generating a new and empty document number which is not yet inserted into the database and the second button (Save) is for inserting data taken from the textbox fields along with the document number into the database,

Now, Suppose two users are logged into that page at the same moment and both of them wants to insert data to the database, Assume user1 presses the "Add New" button and got a document number, for instance, 1000 and at the same time user2 also presses the "Add New" button and get the same document number that is already assigned to user1 because user1 has not yet pressed the "Save" button, which means that the document number 1000 does not even contain a single row in database because no user have yet pressed the "Save" button.

If user1 has pressed the "Save" button, inserting data into database with document number 1000 and then user2 comes and presses "Add New", he will get an incremented value i.e. 1001, and it works fine for me.

My question is that how do I assign different document numbers if both users presses the "Add New" button simultaneously?

Can anyone please help me out of this? and yes, Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You create a new empty document record with a number when "Add" is pressed, so that the number is then allocated to the first user and can't be allocated to the second, who will then get the next number when they click "Add" and you create a new empty document record for them with a new number

Comment: Agreed on immediate ID allocation. You're just going to accept breaks in your ID sequences if a user hits "add new" but never saves it. Ie you'll have lots of "draft" documents effectively.

Comment: Don't confuse the public document number with the private, internal PK. You can have some kind of time limit, so if a document isn't saved its document number is released after a short period of time

Answer (score -1):

```
public static $is_locked = false;

function issue_document_number($params_if_required){
   //for core php write this line 
   global $is_locked; 
   $is_locked = true;
   //for OOP, if you are in class
   $this->is_locked = true;

   //make your calculations here to get desired number

   $is_locked = false;       
   return $document_number;
}
```

at calling check if function is locked `sleep` for 1 or 2 seconds and call again as

```
while($is_locked==true){
   sleep(1);
}
$my_unique_number = issue_document_number($params_if_required);
```

make your query and add in DB

Comment: What exactly will this achieve, as each PHP request runs in its own thread and has no direct communication with any other thread? Every thread has its own `$is_locked` and can't see the `$is_locked` of any other thread

Comment: only mentioned function can issue id to all requests, while it is restricted to issue 1 at a time, so other requests will wait for him untill that function gets free.

Comment: No, it won't, because there's nothing in that function that will stop it running for another request in another thread.... each request will runs its own copy of that function in its own thread, completely independently of each other. You seem to misunderstand what `global` means..... `global` does __not__ mean "across all threads"

Comment: then it is better to save that `$is_locked` value in DB or in a txt file at server

Comment: You need to "lock" something that's accessible from all threads, whether that's a file (which can be problematic if you're running multiple webservers unless you set up a shared drive accessible to all servers for that file), or a database, or even a cache store like memcache or redis